# On Premise TFS Code and Builds Linked to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I would like to use Visual Studio Team Services for Work Items tracking, and use our on-premise installation for source code, builds, etc.  Is this possible?  If so, do the TFS versions need to match?

Comment: Why split the two components? Is putting the source in VSTS a security concern for you or do you just want to give externals access to your backlog?  Could you upgrade your on-premise to 2015 U1 instead to get similar functionality?  A commercial product like TaskTop would probably do a job synchronising Work Items between the two systems but would come at a cost

Comment: @rerwinRR, essentially I'm trying to navigate through political waters.  Company policy is that source code stays on-prem, but our TFS admins are not capable/willing to supporting TFS in a way that works for our team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're using TFVC, if you're using Git the answer will be a bit different.

I guess it could work, but you would lose the ability to link work items and changes together.

You could just reference the work items in commit messages, for example:

```
Fix #123: No longer crashes.
```

But the association would not work.

If you had on premise build and source, everything would work, it would really be like using TFS with a separate Work Item software, I know some people use Jira instead.

As there will be no integration between the 2 the versions needn't match.

If you moved your source control to VSTS, you can keep your build agents locally, there's a cost to it IIRC, but it is possible.

Comment: Yes, using TFVC.  The integration is key, so unfortunately this won't work for us.  Thanks.